# Where to download Print Widget for ArcGIS Flex Viewer 3.4?

Tags: printing, widget, arcgis-flex-viewer

I would like to download the Print Widget for ArcGIS Flex Viewer 3.4 which contains Scale Units like below:

[image]

Does anyone know where I can do that, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Flex App Builder 3.4 or up the following help doc, will be useful.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#//01m300000036000000

Comment: Welcome to the site, Tracey.  It is preferable to put link-only answers such as these as comments because if the links ever become defunct, so to does the answer.  The alternative would be to describe how the link is helpful and provides a solution.